# Spotlight search results priority

Tags: macos, spotlight, search

I noticed recently (could be caused by upgrade to 10.10.4) that Spotlight is changing order of the search results dynamically as you type and OS X installed apps have no more the highest priority (I am almost sure this was the case before).

For example searching for the Caffeine app:

1. Open Spotlight
2. Type **"caf"**

The top hit starts off with the app I'm looking for (yay!)

[image]

3. Press **"f"** so the search term is now **"caff"**

[image]

Wikipedia entry is now the first result and hitting enter opens the Safari.app instead of the Caffeine.app :(

I mostly used Spotlight for quick app opening, which is now much slower because I always have to double-check that I am actually opening the app instead of Safari.

Is it somehow possible to disable this behavior or prioritize installed apps over Internet search results?

Answer (score 9):

System Preferences lets you choose what is displayed, but (since 10.9?) it no longer lets you select the order/priority of results. It would be nice to have that functionality back. I find that I'm constantly opening/launching something I didn't mean to because of the dynamic ordering of results in 10.11.

Comment: there are some posts that claim that unchecking stuff does not work.
It did work for me just now. May 2023. MacOs 12....

Answer (score 3):

I have noticed that as I use Spotlight, it begins to "learn" my search preferences.

For example: search `caf`, then select Caffeine. Repeat.

After a few times, Caffeine should become the dominant result.

---

Additionally, you can turn on or off what Spotlight returns in System Preferences.

- Go to  > **System Preferences**
- Select **Spotlight**
- In the **Search Results** tab, deselect items you don't wish to see in results.

[image: Spotlight Preferences]

Comment: Is this "learning" feature still there? Spotlight doesn't seem to learn from me https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418959/remove-specific-top-hits-from-spotlight-results

Comment: Well, this answer was 6 years ago.  Big Sur seems to have issues now with Spotlight.  See this article from MacMost: https://macmost.com/dealing-with-big-sur-spotlight-previews-and-other-problems.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Tag to the item to see if that helps.

1. focus on the item and `cmd+I` to Get Info.
2. In the "Add Tags" field, add something like `caff`.

In my experience, the Tags seem to bump up the item in Spotlight.

Comment: For my purpose, it seems we can't add comments or tags to System Preferences app in Finder, unfortunately.

Comment: this. no i do not want search priorities to prefer a specific document written 4 years ago and unmodified and unaccessed since over system preferences windows..

Answer (score -1):

While we can't reorganize these easily you can at least filter the search. You can use any of these filters:

> kind:application
>   kind:applications
>   kind:app
>   kind:contact
>   kind:contacts
>   kind:folder
>   kind:folders
>   kind:image
>   kind:images
>   kind:movie
>   kind:movies
>   kind:music
>   kind:audio
>   kind:jpeg
>   kind:pict
>   kind:text
>   kind:rtf
>   kind:osxdaily
>   kind:pdf
>   kind:pdfs
>   kind:system preferences
>   kind:preferences
>   kind:bookmark
>   kind:bookmarks
>   kind:font
>   kind:fonts
>   kind:presentations
>   kind:presentation
>   kind:email
>   kind:emails
>   kind:mail message
>   kind:mail messages
>   kind:event
>   kind:events
>   kind:reminder
>   kind:reminders

And even

> kind:application
>   kind:pdf
>   kind:jpeg
>   kind:word
>   kind:folder
>   kind:image
>   kind:audio
>   date:today
>   date:yesterday
>   date:>1/1/2016

Comment: This is nice information, but doesn't answer the question, and is less convenient in most cases than just using the arrow key to select the desired result.