# Remove specific top hits from Spotlight results

Tags: keyboard, spotlight, search

For some searches, Spotlight shows strange top hits. I often want to open the "Sound" System Preferences pane using Spotlight. But when I type `sound` it *always* shows "DaftCloud for SoundCloud" from the App Store as the top hit. I have never intentionally chosen this item. I have probably hit it a couple of times by mistake, but the vast majority of the time, I navigate one step down using the keyboard and choose "Sound". I rarely listen to music, and never to "DaftCloud" and I never use "SoundCloud". This top hit is weird to me. (Is Apple selling top hits on Spotlight?)

[image: top hit for sound]

I have seen claims that [Spotlight can "learn" from user behavior](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/210710/12219). This doesn't seem to be the case here. I have even intentionally opened "Sound" repeatedly using Spotlight, and it still shows "SoundCloud" first.

Interestingly, typing `soun` (without the final `d`) shows the "Sound" preference pane first, but as soon as I complete the word `sound`, it switches to "SoundCloud". (Again, is Apple selling the "sound" keyword?)

Anyway, I want the "Sound" preference pane to be the top hit for `sound`. Is there any way to achieve this?

I have explored the Spotlight "Search Results" settings. But they don't seem to offer a way to remove App Store suggestions. I cannot remove "Applications" because that will remove the "Sound" preferences from the results.

Some sources claim that I should be able [to drag around the "Search Results" in settings](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/2o9763/how_do_you_move_items_to_the_top_in_the_spotlight/), but they don't move for me.

I can force "Sound" preferences to the top by using the search query `kind:system preferences sound`, but that is absurdly long to type.

Comment: It is not just you. I can reproduce your results including `soun`. I mostly use Alfred rather than Spotlight - it more predictable, but needs more work to configure.

Comment: I would say that this is normal and expected behavior of any machine learning search/filtering. System offers it’s best suggestion as default and if you don’t accept it then it means it’s not what you are looking for and if you enter next letter makes next best guess as default. What is the problem? Desired results with less typing? Shouldn’t it be the objective of every computr user?

Comment: @AivarPaalberg To me it feels natural to type `sound` to reach the "Sound" pane. I don't pause after every keystroke to check the result, and I don't want to have to learn special abbreviations like `soun` for `sound`. I wouldn't call it expected "learning" to consistently ignore that I always choose the second result rather than the first.

Comment: I'll chime in with a recommendation for [Raycast](http://raycast.com) over Alfred. I find it to have a cleaner interface and generally nicer to use; more Spotlight-alike.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck **Siri Suggestions** in System Preferences / Spotlight.

That should prevent SoundClound from showing up. :-)

Comment: I don't want to remove that functionality completely.

Comment: I don't have this option in big sur, even though official apple docs says this is how to disable it. No "Siri Suggestions" in the list.